# MMOs based on .Net?

Tags: mmo

Are there any real MMOs where the server engine is based on .Net?

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4872/what-languages-are-used-to-develop-mmorpgs-like-eve-online-and-wow/4881#4881

Comment: Are we talking engines/libraries for MMOs, or actual MMOs?

Comment: Converted this to CW as this is really just a "list of" question.

Answer (score 9):

[RunUO](https://code.google.com/p/runuo/) and [SunUO](http://www.sunuo.org/) are free Ultima Online servers. Ultima Online client can be downloaded for free.

> SunUO is a free Ultima Online server for Linux/Mono and Windows.NET, based on RunUO. Ultima Online is a commercial MMORPG by Origin / Electronic Arts.

Answer (score 6):

[Photon Socket Server](http://www.exitgames.com/References) is a middleware provider which is using C++ as the underlying framework but the bulk of the logic (i.e. what you have access to) is using .NET.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, those are Russian games, but I assure you they're very real MMOs and have servers made with .NET. I worked on these servers myself, in fact (-8

[Arena Online](http://arena.ru)

[Elements of war](http://www.elements-of-war.com/)

Comment: dont worry!)) I think it is not matter Russian/Brazilian/American/German/etc if guys are creative. So if you wanna know "King's Bounty: The Legend" was made by Russian company "Katauri Interactive" http://www.kings-bounty.com/eng/screens.php

Comment: I only worried that you might not understand the language on these sites. Of course, being a Russian game developer myself, I know of King's Bounty and lots of other great Russian games. Lots of bad ones too (-8

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any commercial MMOs off the top of my head, but the [NetGore](http://www.netgore.com/) Engine, the successor to the powerful [vbGore](http://www.vbgore.com/Main_Page) Engine, is looking pretty good. NetGore is currently in very active development with a growing community.

Answer (score 2):

Second Life runs (at least partially) using managed code. They run on MONO, which is a Linux port of .NET. It's possible they're just hosting .NET within C++ for the scripts, but they are running it at least partially.

Answer (score 1):

Lord of the Rings Online's client uses .NET 1.1. Not sure about the server. I think [Turbine](https://www.turbine.com/)'s games (LotRO, DDO, Asheron's Call) use .NET.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea of the server side but the DDO client throws exceptions that look like .net when it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

[Vindictus](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=vindictus+youtube) server is fully written in .Net. Vindictus offers only one logical shard with hundreds of thousands of simultaneous users, which can be done via function and data distributed computing techniques.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure that CCP Games uses some .NET components on their servers.

Comment: Answers should be fact, and wherever possible support that fact with references (links). Welcome to GD.SE.